# Suspension liquid for ferrofluid that makes it float

Tags: solvents, density

I am currently devising a project to create a kinetic sculpture, similar to [Sachiko Kodama](http://sachikokodama.com). Does anyone know any suspension liquids that when applied, the ferrofluid floats on top?

Comment: Given that ferrofluid lava lamps now exist, this suggests that what you want to do is possible. I hope you succeed!